# Serilog Request Logging to Application Insights is logging as Trace

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog

I have the following code in my Main

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
        configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"],
              new CustomConverter())
        .CreateLogger();
```

With a `.UseSerilog();` in my `CreateHostBuilder` method.

And then in my `Configure`

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Logs are arriving at application insights but `Requests` are being logged as `Traces`

I believe this is due to `app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();` not knowing about `App Insights` and its just firing off a simple log and the App Insights does not know its a Request Trace log so it just logs it as a `Trace`

How can I make the logs produced by `UseSerilogRequestLogging` log as a `Request` in `App Insights`?

Comment: I have same issue, would love a resolution

Comment: we just didn't use Serilog for this, just let `AppInsights` do the logging for `AppInsights`

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue. Seems like there's a need for custom `TraceTelemetryConverter` that checks if `logEvent` SourceContext is comming from `Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware` and if yes then instead of creating `TraceTelemetry` you would need a `RequestTelemetry`.